# Oracle Substring get the maximum of the number

Tags: oracle

I have a table with below data

```
-------------
SOURCE_CD
-------------
100-CITIB001
100-CITIB002
100-CITIB003
100-COSMO001
100-COSMO002
100-COSMOSS3
```

I need to substring the last three characters and pick the maximum number of the result. I use the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(SOURCE_CD,10))
AS SOURCE_CD FROM SOURCE_TBL 
WHERE SOURCE_CD LIKE '100-CITIB%';
```

This will return '003' as that is the maximum of the SOURCE_CD starting with '100-CITIB'. Likewise for '100-COSMO' the result will be 'SS3'. But I need to modify this query to check if the last three characters are numbers and get the maximum of the number.

In this case the result for '100-COSMO' should be '002' as it is the maximum number in the table.

Can anyone help in modifying the query to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a regular expression saying that the last three characters of the column have to be numeric.

```
with source_tbl as(
   select '100-CITIB001' as source_cd from dual union all
   select '100-CITIB002' as source_cd from dual union all
   select '100-CITIB003' as source_cd from dual union all
   select '100-COSMO001' as source_cd from dual union all
   select '100-COSMO002' as source_cd from dual union all
   select '100-COSMOSS3' as source_cd from dual
)
select max(substr(source_cd, -3)) -- Max of the last 3 characters
  from source_tbl
 where regexp_like(source_cd, '[[:digit:]]{3}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

define this func

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function is_number(param varchar2) return NUMBER
                            as
                              ret number;
                            begin
                               ret := to_number(param);
                               return 1;
                            exception
                               when others then return 0;
                            end;
/
```

then use this query;

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(SOURCE_CD,10))
AS SOURCE_CD FROM SOURCE_TBL 
WHERE SOURCE_CD LIKE '100-CITIB%'
and is_number(SUBSTR(SOURCE_CD,10))=1
```